# Calculate mean cell values over different files

Tags: python, r, file

From about 50000 unstructured text files with about 1 million values (all numbers) I need to calculate the mean value for each cell the mean value over all 50.000 files.

The structure of the files is  for example

```
4.7  3.9  5.9  6.2  6.6   6.6   6.5  4.7  5.5  11.2 
21.9 12.4  5.6  4.5  5.8  6.7  5.4 3.6 3.9 0.7 0.8
```

and I need the mean over all files , for each cell position.

So for example, I need the mean for all first elements in the text files, over all 50.000 text files (but not only for the first element, but for all elements).

Any ideas how to do this in R or Python ?

Edited: Additional Example (very very simplified)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0kpT.png)

I want to calculate the mean value in a new file (MEAN) as illustrated in the link below based on the cell values in file1, file 2 and file 3.  But, it should be an automated script because it are not 3 but 50.000 files and many 100thousand values in each file.

Comment: It is not clear whether you have memory constraint or not in loading 50000 files with 1 million values each.  In `R`, usual way is to read the dataset into a `list`. and use `Reduce("+", lst)/length(lst)`

Comment: What happens to these values? Do you put them in the 50000 files? In a list? In another file? In what format?

Comment: there is no memory constraint. I have 50 000 files with many values, what I need to do is create a new file, the 50 001 st file, with for each cell in the file, the mean value over the 50 000 files.  I received the files in .txt format but I already succeeded to read the data in R in a list (for each file), but I need to have for each element in the list ,the mean value over the 50.000 list, and that value should be stored in a new file.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/  Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Comment: The question fits very well in what is described in on topic and how to ask

Comment: The only thing I not succeed in is how to calculate the mean over DIFFERENT files for specific cells, as illustrated in the examples. It is not about calculating a mean or something ...

with a lot of R code I already structured the unstructured text files to lists in R (1 list for 1 file). I have not shown the code because it's not relevant to answer the question and only will cause confusion and distraction.

Comment: @BramV Does your  all files got same number of points? If not what will you like to do when one file got less number of points?

Comment: @MKR, this I was already able to solve earlier, in some filles NA values are added at the positions where values lack, so all files have now the same number of points

Comment: @BramV No worries. You can try my solution. Since, your response came late, I had worked out a solution that can fit even files with different number of values. You can try.

Comment: ok, thanks, I will try your solution very soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python, I would suggest a simple approach, hoping I got you.
You could get all files, then iterate over them in order to take all space separated numbers to put in a list. All these lists will be stored in another list to transform in a matrix, easy to manage with numpy.
Here I show you an example.

0. Put all files in the same directory, for instance fdir

1. Get all the files names

```
import os
flist = os.listdir(fdir)
```

2. Now iterate through the files list. Assuming that is not important the formatted position into the file, but just the ordinal sequence (i.e. first, second, ... not top-left, top-right,..).

```
import numpy as np
numbers = [] #list of files numbers lists
for text in flist:
with open(filename,'r') as f:
       ftext = f.read().split() #the file has only space-separated numbers 
       ftext = [float(n) for n in ftext]
       numbers.append(  np.array( ftext ) )
```

4. Convert the list of lists in a matrix

```
numbers = np.vstack(numbers)
```

5. Do your operations..

**Example**:
 summing over first cell of every files, means to sum over the first column of the latter matrix, so:

```
sum_over_first_cells = np.sum( numbers[:,0] )
```

Hope it will be helpful.

Comment: Thank you, it was helpful, but, I need in the end to sum over all cells and not only the first and it's still a lot of work with this solution (because >10000 cells), but I will try to search a solution for it.

Comment: Do you mean a sum over each column?

Comment: No, the sum_over_first_cells statement for all cells and not only the first cell. But I have solved it with adding a loop, defining x=0 in first step , with x on the place numbers[:,x] and than stating that after executing: x+=1

Comment: Well, to sum every numbers in the matrix (therefor every cells) just use numbers.sum() .
If you wanted to sum over each column use numbers.sum(axis=0).
In other words, numpy.sum() is very helpful in your situation, check the doc if you have time :).
Glad to see that you solved anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If the files have the exact same structure, you can load one file in an array, then load another file and sum to that first array. At the end you just divide your array by the number of files.

Example:

```
File 1:
1 2 3 4 5

File 2:
5 4 3 2 1

File 3:
0 3 0 3 0
```

Read file 1

```
Array = {1,2,3,4,5}
```

Read and sum File 2

```
Array = {1+5, 2+4, 3+3, 4+2, 5+1} = {6, 6, 6, 6, 6}
```

Read and sum File 3

```
Array = {6+0, 6+3, 6+0, 6+3, 6+0} = {6, 9, 6, 9, 6}
```

At the end you divide your array by the number of files (here there are 3 files)

```
Result = {6/3, 9/3, 6/3, 9/3, 6/3} = {2,3,2,3,2}
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to read all files using `scan`. Then merge data in one data.frame using `stack`. First assign `position` (cell number) after grouping data on file number. Then group on `position` to calculate `mean` for each position using `dplyr` as:

```
librar(dplry)

#Read all files. It will generate a list with vector of values for each file
myfiles = lapply(list.files(path="D:\\data\\", pattern="*.txt", full.names = TRUE), 
                                                                scan)

# Name list sequentially. Name will help to `stack`
names(myfiles) <- seq_along(myfiles)

# stack will generate a merge data.frame
stack(myfiles) %>% group_by(ind) %>%
  mutate(position = row_number()) %>%
  group_by(position) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(values,  na.rm = TRUE))

# # A tibble: 55 x 2
#   position  mean
#  <int> <dbl>
# 1        1  16.2 
# 2        2  9.57
# 3        3  5.70
# 4        4  5.07
# 5        5  6.07
# 6        6  6.67
# 7        7  5.77
# 8        8  3.97
# 9        9  4.43
# 10       10  4.20
# # ... with 45 more rows
```

**Data:**

```
# File1.txt
4.7  3.9  5.9  6.2  6.6   6.6   6.5  4.7  5.5  11.2 

# File2.txt
21.9 12.4  5.6  4.5  5.8  6.7  5.4 3.6 3.9 0.7 0.8 

# File3.txt
21.9 12.4  5.6  4.5  5.8  6.7  5.4 3.6 3.9 0.7 0.8 21.9 12.4  5.6  4.5 
5.8  6.7  5.4 3.6 3.9 0.7 0.8 21.9 12.4  5.6  4.5  5.8  6.7  5.4 3.6
3.9 0.7 0.8 21.9 12.4  5.6  4.5  5.8  6.7 5.4 3.6 3.9 0.7 0.8 21.9 
12.4  5.6  4.5  5.8  6.7  5.4 3.6 3.9 0.7 0.8
```